# RegEx not working as expected /(d).\1/

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am beginner in RegEx so I am reading the info page of regEx on stackoverflow.

> eg: /(d).\1/ matches and captures 'dad' in "abcdadef" while
>   /(?:.d){2}/ matches but doesn't capture 'cdad'.

I tried :-

```
var pattern=/(d).\1/


var val="abcdadef";

console.log(pattern.exec(val));
```

It shows array of ["dad","d"] but i don't know why ?
As said in info it just only capture the "dad" why it is capturing two values in array?.
And what is the use of '\1' in the end of pattern ?

Please provide me more info how to use it.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Read the documentation of RegExp.exec? The second element in the array is the content of the first capturing group.

Comment: I read it .It say it will return array or null but my question is why array consist two values instead of one ?

Comment: The info text is misleading. It matches `dad` and captures `d`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck that's what boggle my mind thanks so info should clearly mention it. :-)

Comment: @squiroid, read my answer. Regex will attempt to put the entire match first and that it will follow it by whatever capturing groups the regex expression has. capturing groups means () in the regex expression.

Comment: I've edited the example in the regex info wiki accordingly.

Comment: KlasLindbäck Thanks :-) and @one who gave me negative thanks :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you use (), you're telling regex to match the in between () and store it as a capturing group. Each match will have capturing groups of its own. Try your expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/qX9wF3/1). A regex match object is normally a collection that contains the entire match of the regex followed by capturing groups of that match.

**Edit:** As per your comment below, here's an another pattern `(m).\1` and the text upon which we're executing the regex is mum.
In this example, regex will attempt to do the following:

1. match the literal `m` and hence we used `()`, it's going to store the match in a capturing group. This capturing group will make it to the match collection later.
2. `.` will match any character other than newline so in our case, it will match the literal `u`.
3. `\1` will attempt to match the next character using the first matching group as a pattern and that would be the literal `m` in our case.

The final result will be the regex match of `mum` and the only capturing group would be `m`.

Comment: can you explain the use of /1 in the regEx ?

Comment: Open the link in my answer. There's a description of \1, the / the delimiter of the regex.

Comment: \1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

Comment: can you explain with example ?

Comment: \1 means that the regex will attempt to match text using the first matching capturing group as pattern, in your case the letter d. This will result in matching the second d in dad.